# Why did Aquaman feel that Mera's plan was a little out of order?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, aquaman-2018

In the Ring of Fire, Mera intervenes and gets Arthur out of there before Orm can 
strike a fatal blow. The two get away in her watercraft and are pursued by Orm's men:

> Aquaman: So, what's the plan?
>
> Mera: The plan was to recover Atlan's trident, then challenge Orm.
>
> Aquaman: Okay, **so we're doing things a little out of order**.

Why did Aquaman feel that Mera's plan was a little out of order?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## He didn't

He's saying that the order they are doing things in is out of order compared to the order of the original plan. They originally wanted to get Atlan's Trident and then challenge Orm but they actually challenged Orm and then go to get Atlan's Trident.

---

Full disclaimer, I haven't seen the film so am answering solely off of the context in the question/

Comment: This is correct...but it's mostly Mera's plan.  Arthur doesn't know a thing about politics, and he was goaded in to challenging Orm when he did; it wasn't part of any plan.  Arthur is trying to save face, by acting like his challenge is just a slight alteration to her plan, instead of a horrible idea that's likely to get him killed.

Answer (score 1):

It was the other way around.

What Mera said was the original plan. But instead of following it, Arthur challenges Orm first.

So it's Arthur who is doing things out of order.

He's trying to make a lame joke covering up what he just did.

To summarise: Arthur was breaking the plan, Mera wasn't.